# Getting error message for "CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Sytem.Threading.Tasks.Task<BookListRazor.Model.Book>' to 'BookListRazor.Model.Book'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to follow an tutorial from an online source (Udemy class) and there appears to be an error in my code that I tried searching and even reviewed multiple times as to why I am getting the error.

First off I am new to c#/.net/razor which is the tech stack that is being taught in the class. The instructor did not receive an error in his code so I am lost ( he also does not appear to be responding to anyone).

So I have this controller called BookControllers which consist of the code below

```
enter code here  
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BookListRazor.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BookListRazor.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Book")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BookController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public BookController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            return Json(new { data = await _db.Book.ToListAsync() });
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var bookFromDb = _db.Book.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
            if (bookFromDb == null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while Deleting" });
            }

            _db.Book.Remove(bookFromDb); //This is where the error is being produced at in the code from the parameter that is being provide.
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete successful" });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `await` on this line:

```
var bookFromDb = await _db.Book.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
```

More generally, any time you find yourself having a `Task<T>` when you were expecting a `T`, then you're missing an `await` somewhere that unwraps the `T` from the `Task<T>`.

Comment: Of course its something as simple as that. 

Thank you!